# Separar y sacar de un String cierto valor Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lo que deseo es imprimir por pantalla el mes de una fecha que introduzca. Para ello uso un input y lo paso por una funcino que emplea la libería "re" y le hago un split re.

El funcionamiento sería el siguiente:

1. Introduzco fecha ("12/12/2012" o "12-12-2012" o "12 de diciembre de 2012")
2. El mes es: X

Este es el código

```
 # Para lo que quiero hacer debo importar una libreria de Python
 # Con esta libreria admitiré más delimitadores en la busqueda
import re
# Se crean las variables que recogen los datos y se guardan con valor entero
fechaInput = input("Indique fecha (En el siguiente formato): \n1. 31/12/2020 \t 2. 31-12-2020 \t 3. 31 de enero de 2020 \n")
  
# Creo función
def separador(txt):
    array = re.split(r'\s+', re.sub(r'[,\-./ de]', ' ', txt))
    return array[1]


# Lo saco por pantalla
    print("El mes es: {}".format(separador(fechaInput)))
```

Separa muy bien con "/" y con "-" pero el mes "Febrero" o así largos me imprime la primera letra solo.
¿Qué puede estar mal?

Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en este `re.sub(r'[,\-./ de]', ' ', txt)`

Entiendo que la intención es sustituir la coma, el guión, el punto, la barra, o la palabra "de" por un espacio. Pero no es así como funciona, mira:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[,\-./ de]', ' ', "31 de enero de 2020")
'31     n ro    2020'
```

Como ves, no ha considerado "de" como una palabra, sino como dos letras a sustituir por espacios. En tu cadena ha cambiado todas las apariciones de la "d" o de la "e" por un espacio. Por eso luego el split sólo encuentra una "n".

Si quieres conservar tu idea, no metas "de" dentro de los corchetes, sino fuera y con el operador `|`. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[,\-./ ]|de', ' ', "31 de enero de 2020")
'31   enero   2020'
```

y ahora tu split ya funcionaría.

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Soy algo nuevo en python y todavía no controlo mucho.

Comment: En realidad este problema no era de python, sino de expresiones regulares, pero supongo que serás nuevo también en eso ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado algo como:

```
def separador(txt):
    match = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:/|-|\sde\s)(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)(?:/|-|\sde\s)(\d+)', txt)
    return match.group(2)
```

Esta expresión busca dígitos y meses separados por `/`, `-` o `\sde\s` sin necesidad de substituir nada.

Explicación:

- Primero declaras un grupo de captura para el día. Este grupo busca 1 o mas dígitos. `(\d+)`
- La siguiente parte busca los caracteres que separan el día del mes. Para ello declara un grupo de no captura `(?:)` y luego usa el operador or para encontrar algunos de los separadores, que son `\`, `-`, `\sde\s` (el `\s` es un espacio). Entonces todo junto queda así `(?:/|-|\sde\s)`
- Entonces buscas el mes tanto en números como en texto. Para esto se usa nuevamente el operador or `|` en las expresiones `\d+` y `([a-zA-Z]+)`. Todo junto queda `(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)`
- Finalmente buscas el separador entre mes y años, lo mismo que el paso 2.
- Buscas el año con `(\d+)` y lo pones en un grupo de captura

Puedes probar esta expresión en el debugger de Regex https://regex101.com/r/AIGB9Y/1

Answer (score 0):

Aunque obtienes un valor correcto con los valores de formato `dd/mm/YYYY` y `dd-mm-YYYY` en el caso del formato `31 de enero de 2020` el mes no sería el segundo elemento del array (`array[1]`), te sugiero diferenciar y usar otro split para separar los valores en el caso del tercer formato.

De esta forma obtener el mes funcionaría para los 3 casos:

```
# Para lo que quiero hacer debo importar una libreria de Python
 # Con esta libreria admitiré más delimitadores en la busqueda
import re
# Se crean las variables que recogen los datos y se guardan con valor entero
fechaInput = input("Indique fecha (En el siguiente formato): \n1. 31/12/2020 \t 2. 31-12-2020 \t 3. 31 de enero de 2020 \n")
  
# Creo función
def separador(txt):
    print("txt",txt)
    chars = set('/,-')
    if any((c in chars) for c in txt):
        array = re.split(r'\s+', re.sub(r'[,\-./ de]', ' ', txt))
        return array[1]
    else:
        array = txt.split(" ")
        return array[2]        

# Lo saco por pantalla
print("El mes es: ", separador(fechaInput))
```